# How to avoid SQL Server error on ORDER BY with duplicate columns

Tags: sql-server, portability

*Although this question references PHP, it is not actually PHP-specific, so I have not flagged it as such.*

We have a PHP framework which supports multiple DB back-ends.

There is a generic function in our data object class, which allows you to get records from the underlying table, with a specified criteria and sort order.

It looks something like this:

```
function GetAll($Criteria, $OrderBy = "") {

    ...

    // Add primary key (column 1) to end of order by list,
    // so that returned order is predictable.
    if ($OrderBy != "") {
        $OrderBy .= ", ";
    }
    $OrderBy .= "1";

    ...

    // Build and run query, returning the result as an array.
}
```

If you specify an `$OrderBy` argument of `StaffID` on a `Staff` object, the resulting SQL looks something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM adminStaff ORDER BY StaffID, 1;
```

This works fine on a MySQL back-end, and from my searching of the web it should also be fine on most other DB back-ends.  However, when using SQL Server, we get the following error message:

```
A column has been specified more than once in the order by list.
Columns in the order by list must be unique.
```

This arises because SQL Server disallows the same column appearing multiple times in the ORDER BY clause.  In this case `StaffID` is column 1 and therefore we have multiple instances of the same column.

Is there a way to disable this check in SQL Server?  MySQL provides a lot of options to enable/disable strictness checks and incompatible features - does SQL Server provide anything of that nature that would allow the above query to run without errors?

If not, do you have any suggestions for how we could resolve this in our data-object layer?  Bear in mind we need to maintain compatibility with existing projects which expect this behaviour, so it is not sufficient to only include the first column when `$OrderBy` is blank.

The situation is also slightly complicated in the fact that the field list is customisable elsewhere in the data object configuration, so we can't rely on `*` being used as the field list - it could contain pretty much anything that is valid in a normal SQL field list.  However, if that is asking too much, a solution to the simpler case (as outlined above) would be a good start!

Comment: This is not allowed because logically it doesn't make sense. I would make a couple suggestions to this. First, I would not have my sql in the application, instead I would have it as a stored procedure. Secondly you should avoid ordering by ordinal position because it will come back to bite you at some point. When you change the order of columns in your query the order by will be wrong unless you also remember to update the order by clause. Best to order by column name.

Comment: What is the purpose of still having the "1" as the second order when you have already given a first column to order by? Is it really that important to keep that second order by? Does the application depend on it in anyway?

Comment: Why can't you modify your function to not add column 1 if the order by is already set to use the primary key.  I think that would be much safer than trying to force the database to act differently.

Comment: @SeanLange - We are where we are.  I would probably do this differently if we were starting from scratch, but the question is about finding the best way to make this code portable without breaking existing projects.  btw I completely disagree with stored procedures being the answer to this as they are nearly always non-portable.

Comment: @Niklas / @wes-h In this example, the field is the primary key, but that isn't necessarily the case.  For example, the `$OrderBy` argument may be a Date field, in which case the result will be order by date, and then by column 1.  That is a more obvious use-case, and the kind of thing that would break if we simply omitted the column when `$OrderBy` is non-blank.

Comment: I don't know if it's a good answer (depending on how large your tabels are) or if it's even possible in MySQL, but could you join the table with itself like this? `SELECT A.* FROM adminStaff A INNER JOIN adminStaff B ON A.Id = B.Id ORDER BY B.Id, 1`.

Comment: What kind of backwards compatibility are you dealing with that doesn't allow ordering by the column name?

Comment: This is in our internal PHP framework, so we can't break the framework's API compatibility with the dozens of existing projects which expect that the first column will be automatically added to their order by list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic question - is it possible to suppress this SQL Server restriction on ORDER BY column duplication - was answered by Venu: No it is not.

There are various suggestions (mostly from me) about how you could possibly code around this limitation in a generic manner.  For any future readers, those answers are probably the most helpful if you are adapting an existing system.  (If you are starting from scratch, just try and avoid this situation altogether.)

However, the actual solution that I came to was to add versioning to our internal API for our DBAL.  The API version is now `2` but you can call `setApiVersion(1)` to instruct the back-end to use the old version of the API instead.

v2 is identical to v1* except it no longer automatically adds column 1 to the ORDER BY unless it is completely blank.  Therefore, the SQL Server issue is resolved for new (v2) projects, whilst existing projects can be set to use the v1 API and therefore continue to work correctly (but without SQL server compatibility).

(* Actually, I've taken this opportunity to make some other breaking changes in v2, but that is not relevant to this answer.)

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you are able to sort either by column name or by ordinal position of the column order in the SELECT list.

In your case the column `StaffID` became the ordinal position `1`. Hence SQL Server cannot sort the same result set based on the same column twice.

If you remove the `1` from your query, the problem will be solved.

Avoid using the ordinal position of the column for sorting.

Comment: I think I covered all of this in my question - the question was, is there a way to work round this behaviour without simply dropping the ordinal column number (due to backwards-compatibility issues)?

Comment: @HappyDog, It is not possible to do with SQL Server.

Comment: If you add that to your answer, I will upvote it.  It is the direct answer to my basic question.

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with a couple of potential solutions at the framework level.  All of them have performance implications which would need to be profiled, and in practice that may rule some or all of them out.  However, in theory at least, these are ways that a generic solution could be implemented.

1. Omit the ORDER BY altogether, and do the sorting in code.  Would involve parsing the provided ORDER BY string.  Would be problematic if ORDER BY contained expressions, but I can't remember ever seeing that in our projects, so can probably be ignored.  Probably the slowest solution.
2. Perform the query without the ORDER BY, limiting the results set to a single row.  Use resulting column list to work out whether column 1 is already in the ORDER BY clause, and therefore whether to add it.  Then run the full query.  Would require parsing the provided ORDER BY string.  Query caching *may* mean this won't add as much overhead as it appears.
3. Parse the field list to get the first column name and see if this appears in the ORDER BY clause.  If field list contains `*` or `table.*` would require a schema lookup.  May be too difficult if we need to deal with table aliases and wildcards in combination.
4. Parse ORDER BY string and see if it contains any primary key.  If so it is already uniquely ordered and doesn't require the addition of an extra field.  Would require a schema look-up.
5. Use a sub-select to give us a new instance of the column that we can sort on instead.  Not sure whether SQL Server would still complain that this is the 'same' column, though.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15530346)

Comment: Really?  This _is_ an answer, so I'm not sure why it should be placed within the question.  I can edit this answer to be remove the request for input, if you like?

Comment: Looking at this again it's possible I misread it, I apologize, the last part sounded like a follow-up question

Comment: I've tweaked the wording so it works better as an answer.  I've removed the parts that ask for other opinions and the slightly waffly introduction.

Answer (score 0):

Could you just append '--' to your OrderBy parameter when working with SQL Server and just explicitly define the Order By fields where necessary?

Comment: Wouldn't that just comment-out the OrderBy?  I don't see the benefit of this over simply omitting it (or am I missing something?).

Comment: I thought it would comment out the '1' part of the OrderBy.  E.g.  "ORDER BY UserID--,1".

Comment: Yes, but the point is that we need the '1' part to be present, otherwise code that depends on the ordering that this provides will be affected.

Comment: Ah if the existing queries in the framework are using duplicate columns then this won't work as you say, I was thinking of new queries written for SQL server that need to use your existing GetAll function.

Comment: Ah - I get it.  That might work, though it's a bit of a hack.  Ideally this would be fixed at the framework layer, rather than requiring hacks in the calling code, but it does have the benefit of not affecting performance at all.