# sort a column with duplicate values by another column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a following table:

```
+------+--------+
| Type |Location|
+------+--------+
| 0003 |   US   |
| 0010 |   US   |
| 0007 |   CA   |
| 0013 |   MX   |
| 0003 |   EU   |
| 0007 |   MX   |
| 0219 |   CN   |
+------+--------+
```

I need it sorted by "Location", except when a duplicate is found in the "Type" column. Then the next row should be duplicate (or more duplicates) before proceeding further with sorting by "Location".

Expected result:

```
+------+--------+
| Type |Location|
+------+--------+
| 0007 |   CA   |
| 0007 |   MX   | <---- Exception (duplicate of 0007)
| 0219 |   CN   |
| 0003 |   EU   |
| 0003 |   US   | <---- Exception (duplicate of 0003)
| 0013 |   MX   |
| 0010 |   US   |
+------+--------+
```

I've tried to play with cte and row_number but I couldn't come anywhere close. I am not sure if this was a good approach, but I can't think of any other solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid SQL Server error on ORDER BY with duplicate columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42766186/how-to-avoid-sql-server-error-on-order-by-with-duplicate-columns)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do what you want with a window function in the `order by`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by (min(location) over (partition by type)),
         location
```

Comment: I'm getting syntax error, don't know why, but thanks anyway. `order by location over (partition by type), location` MS SQL 2012

Comment: @user2463808 . . . That is not what this answer says to do.  It has `order by min(location) over (partition by type)`.